# Having multiple builds of same flutter app on android device

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-build

For debugging purposes - I want to have multiple builds of my flutter app. One - should be from google play and few others like "App Name - Dev" Or "App Name - STG". I tried to use flavors and modifying `android:label="@string/app_name"` however I cant install new build of app - android complains with following message - `app not installed as package conflicts with an existing package`

So how do I have multiple builds of same app on my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In device or playstore , app is identified by bundle id and as per error it looks like you are trying to install app with same bundle id which is already installed on device . To make same app different, you need to make bundle id different which you can achieve by flavours . Kindly consider below mentioned code

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationIdSuffix ".free"
        }
        pro {
            applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
        }
    }
}
```

here we have two flavours

1. free
2. pro

now both will have different bundle id as `applicationIdSuffix` will append string at the end of original bundle id

So for free flavour , it will be `com.example.myapp.free` and for pro flavour , it will be `com.example.myapp.pro`

For more details , you can check this link

https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#groovy

Comment: Thanks bud, that seems to be what Im looking for!